# How to make JavaScript execute in Stack Overflow's "run code snippet"

Tags: support, stack-snippets

```css
div#html,div#css,div#js,div#run{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
div#content{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
textarea{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='html'>html</div>
<div id='css'>css</div>
<div id='js'>js</div>
<div id='run'>run</div>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

The above code snippet contains JavaScript code. When I click `Run code snippet`, the JavaScript code can't execute; no `alert` webpage popup. How can I make it run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Your markup is:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -- >

   var  content=document.body.innerHTML;
   alert(content) 

<!-- language: lang-css -->
```

But the Markdown must contain `<!-- language: lang-js -->` before the JavaScript segment, eg:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -- >

<!-- language: lang-js -->

   var  content=document.body.innerHTML;
   alert(content) 

<!-- language: lang-css -->
```

(note: to avoid problems with the snippet *actually trying to render* in this answer, in the above code blocks, the `-- >` at the end of the first line needs to be replaced with `-->`)

Result:

```js
var  content=document.body.innerHTML;
   alert(content)
```

```css
div#html,div#css,div#js,div#run{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
}
div#content{
    clear:both;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
textarea{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='html'>html</div>
<div id='css'>css</div>
<div id='js'>js</div>
<div id='run'>run</div>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```

When in doubt, start over by pressing the Snippet button (or Control-M) and pasting in the HTML/CSS/JS again.

[image]

Also, it helps to only edit the snippet when inside the snippet editor interface - if you try to edit a snippet's content outside the snippet editor, just in the Markdown, it's a lot harder to manage; these sorts of mistakes are easy to make.

Comment: Does this mean that code fences (e.g. `\`\`\`js` instead of `<!-- language: lang-js -->`) don't work with code snippets?

Comment: That's right, since Stack Snippets are not just plain code blocks; Stack Snippets require their own particular syntax in order to be runnable.

Comment: Ooh, I wonder if the people implementing highlight.js, those who got code fences working, and the people who implemented snippets work within earshot of each other. Fight! ;)

Comment: [List of allowed language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109). Wouldn't `lang-javascript` work as well?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's not an issue of syntax highlighting, but of Stack Snippet-specific syntax, which determines how stuff that comes after `<!-- begin snippet:` gets rendered (if it gets rendered at all)

Comment: +1 for: "edit the snippet when inside the snippet editor interface" ...